# ggplot2 ggallin Error in `as.trans()`: ! `trans` must be a character vector or a transformer object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was able to use ggallin::pseudolog10_trans() to plot log10 x-scale with negative numbers a week ago, but now I am getting the error message:

```
Error in `as.trans()`:
! `trans` must be a character vector or a transformer object
```

At this point, the scripts available from the help page do not work:

```
set.seed(1234)
ggplot(data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=runif(100)),aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(trans=ssqrt_trans)
Error in `as.trans()`:
! `trans` must be a character vector or a transformer object
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go and get the latest version on github -> `packageVersion("ggallin")` = `0.1.1.1001`.

Using `install.packages("ggallin")` causes the error (package version 0.1.1).

```
# get snapshot from github (may be buggy)
if (require(devtools)) {
  install_github('shabbychef/ggallin')
}

library(ggplot2)
library(ggallin)

set.seed(1234)
ggplot(data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=runif(100)),aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(trans=ssqrt_trans)
```

[image]